# Why does Mumble interfere with Steam?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, mumble

[image]

Why does Mumble require me to close Steam or Chrome on Setup?

What does it change within Steam that makes it necessary and why does it touch it at all?

Comment: German is hard to understand >.< (at least for me =P)

Comment: How does that justify a close tag and down voting? Also, I described what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't downvote you =X Also, the close vote, I believe, is because Mumble is not game related. It's more like a Mumble issue, not a game issue. so `off-topic`. But, as I'm not sure about it, I'm not voting (yet) to close your question. PS: The comment was a funny comment only =/

Comment: I think it is very well on topic. Gaming related software is allowed, so this is related to gaming since mumble is used by many gamers. Also, it relates to Steam. So I can't see why it should be offtopic.

Comment: weird, I never have issues with mumble and steam working together, though I do give steam admin privileges and not mumble, so that may be it.

Comment: Does it happen only when you install it, or does it continue when you try to use it. i.e. Can you **USE** Mumble the same time as Steam and Chrome?

Comment: @user28015 Try put extra information about usage (as [Ilya said](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98852/why-does-mumble-interfere-with-steam#comment134849_98852)) and system configuration (maybe it'll be helpful, like what OS you are using) PS: [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7574893#7574893)

Comment: I'd bet it's either some system/common file or the app is just being overprotective and asking you to shut down most/all open applications. I know several people who use steam and mumble and don't have problems, so don't assume this means they interfere

Comment: @BenBrocka is probably correct -- if I had to make a guess, I'd suggest that it needs to hook something into either the webkit or flash libraries.

Comment: This seems to be unanswerable by anyone but the Mumble devs.  To that end, I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: It is possible that it needs to close those other programs because it needs to modify audio settings and it can not do so while programs which are using those audio settings are open.  Others have seen a [conflict between Mumble and Steam](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1877587), though I don't know if that is related.

Comment: Also, for those that are interested - Google says the first few lines say "Files are used
Some files that need to be updated are currently in use"

Comment: @user28015 - Mumble and Steam use the same system files.

Comment: I did not have that issue, but I run Mumble installers (I use PR and FH2 Mumble) and the app itself in an administrator mode as some functions become unavailable otherwise, so check if that helps.

Comment: @EBongo it is not about changing audio settings. Mumble has its own audio settings that it uses to talk to the system. Aside from that, only exclusive mode and audio attenuation should be able to influence other applications - but both of those are provided by the system, thus Mumble does not directly influence those other applications but only indirectly, through the operating system.

Comment: @Kissaki I am by no means a software/driver expert, just trying to help based on the OS message.  I get that Mumble would be independent at run time, but the message seems to indicate that other apps are blocking the Mumble *install*.  I often wonder if the installers are really blocked by a conflict with an open app, or they just blindly force you to close those apps - maybe there isn't really a conflict, but the installer thinks there is?

Comment: The conflict is in mumbles overlay DLL that is to be replaced, as it is still in use by the system/application. As it is still in use, windows can not simply replace the DLL, hence the installer asks for the processes to be closed, so the DLL then not in use can be replaced with the new file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Mumbles overlay enabled and Mumble running, it will inject into any applications using Direct3D (DirectX). In this case, this seemingly happened to chrome.exe and steam.exe.

As the overlay DLL is updated the injected code should be invalidated/dropped, thus the installer lists these applications and informs that they should be closed.

As the overlays in-memory information structure may change between versions and as that information is shared system-wide (shared memory) using both “old” injected code as well as “new” injected code (previous vs. current Mumble overlay DLL version) is discouraged - and thus the applications should be closed.

In the current code-base of Mumble steam.exe as well as chrome is blacklisted (since [2012](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/blame/master/overlay/overlay_blacklist.h#L63)/[2011](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/blame/master/overlay/overlay_blacklist.h#L41)). I would guess you still use a very outdated version of the default blacklist. In Mumbles settings you can use restore to default to set the new defaults as your current blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Mumble .msi install package as follows:

```
msiexec.exe /i mumble-1.2.4.msi /l* log.txt
```

Continue the installation until the dialog appears and look at the last couple of lines in `log.txt`. It should be pretty clear which file that is in use. My guess is `msvcr100.dll`.

Comment: There would be no technical reason for that. If properly programmed, a .dll can handle multiple clients that need it when running. IT is also not necessary to close other programs that use this file unless you want to replace it. And if a simple voice program wants to replace the C/C++ Runtime of my OS, then I would be really worried and assume malware.

Comment: I doubt `msvcr100.dll` would be an issue. If it is listed where you described, I doubt this approach to finding the culprit is a good approach.

Comment: @Assylum Replacing a shared file is exactly what the installer wants to do according to OP. Inspecting the latest Mumble .msi reveals that its tables do indeed contain install references for msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll to _SystemFolder_ (which, depending on your Windows and how you run the installer may or may not be shared between applications). In fact, these two files are the *only* files in the installer that seem to be marked for installation to a system folder. Historically it has been very common for applications to update common libraries system-wide. I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @Kissaki See my comment above. As these are the only two files to be installed to a system folder, it would make sense. Nevertheless, it was a *guess*, and I *do* believe finding the conflicting file using the command line arguments I provided is a good approach to finding the culprit. Why would it not be a good idea?